# How do we compare cloud watch metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to AWS and cloudwatch. I have two different metrics and want to compare both the metrics like for timestamp t1 what is the difference between the two metrics m1-m2? Is there any way I can do that? Currently I am able to see them differently.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch metrics can be compared in the following ways:

Dashboards: Create a custom CloudWatch dashboard to visualize multiple metrics side-by-side for comparison.

Alarms: Set CloudWatch alarms on specific metrics to trigger notifications or automate actions when certain thresholds are breached.

Metric Math: Use CloudWatch's Metric Math expressions to perform mathematical operations on two or more metrics and compare the results.

Insights: Use CloudWatch Logs Insights to analyze log data and compare metrics across multiple dimensions.

Third-party tools: Integrate CloudWatch with third-party tools like Grafana, Datadog, or New Relic to visualize and compare metrics in more detail.